# kotlin geocoder.getFromLocationName getting hung

Tags: android, kotlin, geocoder

So I tried to convert a text address into coordinates using geocoder.getFromLocationName() in kotlin

```
import android.location.Geocoder


val geocoder = Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault())
try {
    val result = geocoder.getFromLocationName(club.location, 1) // it gets hung here before throw!!
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "${club.location} translates into cordinates : ${result[0].latitude}, ${result[0].longitude}")
}
catch (ex : Exception){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "${ex.message}")
}
```

but it always catches the exception saying

> 

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: ClientCall started after deadline exceeded: -15.077367176s from now
                                                                                                        at android.location.Geocoder$SynchronousGeocoder.getResults(Geocoder.java:388)
                                                                                                        at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:277)
                                                                                                        at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:202)
```

Is the Geocoder in android not working ? find it hard to believe .. or did I miss anything ?

I tried to look up online but not found helpful responses

Comment: this is causing problem in real devices as well. Did you find the  exact root cause of why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

alright, seems like simulator doesn't work for geocoder usage but real physical device works